# White edge/block to the right of navigation bar?(HTML)

Tags: html, css, web

I made a website with a navigation bar at the top. I used the background element to change its background and it stops where the navigation ends. I also added a background to the rest of the site as a div by itself. The problem is that this extends further than the background of the navigation. This leads to there being a slider at the bottom of the page and a white block to the right of the navigation.

```
.menu-navigation-basic {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-image: url("images/Background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

.menu-navigation-basic a {
    color:  #809098;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 0 20px auto;
    line-height: 2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;

}

.background{
    background-image: url("images/Background.jpg");
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.9;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    position:relative;
    padding-left: 5vw;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `width: 100vw` in `.background`.
Width of `background` element is sum of content's width and padding. And Padding of `body` and `background` is not zero, so, `background` element is wider than `body` and it makes white block.